# How I can I replicate JavaScript's prompt function in a new modal with a password field?

Tags: javascript

I am re-writing a module for an internal employee application. This application currently uses a JavaScript prompt window for some actions and the prompt window is asking for a pin code, unique to each employee. This code is then logged in the system against that certain action.

Unfortunately with the JavaScript prompt window anyone looking at the screen can see the text typed in. I am trying to re-create this prompt function but with a password filter. To do this I have created a Modal and used an input tag with the type set to password.

The only problem I am having is that the Modal code is non-blocking and the checks are now ignored. Previously the prompt function was blocking and the code would wait for a reply.

How can I replicate JavaScript's prompt function and its blocking-ness in a modal?

Comment: You cannot. Rewrite your code to be non-blocking.

Comment: If by "blocking" you mean that the modal, while it's displayed, prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the page - then jQuery's modal might help you.  You just set 'modal: true'.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'checks are ignored'.  Can you be more specific?  Can you post some of your code?

Comment: @Stan at the moment there is a simple if statement that gets the prompt value and compares it, if its all good then the code carry's on executing and will run an update query. At the moment I'm trying to replicate that code because my modal is non-blocking and the query runs anyway and ignores user input. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Bergi I'm afraid its not that simple.

Comment: @Alex: The task to rewrite it might not be, but my statement is: There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using jQuery-UI for this type of a problem.  It's very simple to use and you'll be able to achieve your desired results very quickly.  Here is a simple demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ecq80jd2/

And the code:

```
<body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Enter a value">
        <input type="password" id="test" />
    </div>
    <a href="#">Can't Click Me until a value is entered into dialog box</a>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        if ($("#test").val() != "") {
                            alert($("#test").val());
                            $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```